# R:: How to make a dataframe and attach its column names in a single line in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
parList <- as.data.frame( rbind(
  c("PACKAGE"    ,"OptimizeR"              ),
  c("RCALL"      ,"optimizeR_jar"          ),
  c("var_PRODUCT", "PRODUCT_CODE"          ),
  c("var_JAR"    ,"SUGAR_JAR"              ),
  c("var_JAR"    ,"STRENGTH_JAR"           ),
  c("candidat"   ,"C18"                    ),
  c("benchmark"  ,"L23"                    ),
  c("var_TARGET" ,"PRODUCT_OVERALL_OPINION")
)
)
```

The column names can be attached like this

```
names(parList) <- c("CODE", "VAL")
```

I want to make both in a single line of code. Please advice how this can be achieved? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
parList <- setNames(as.data.frame(..., c("CODE", "VAL"))
```

Or if we are using `data.table`, `setnames` can be used

```
library(data.table)
parList1 <- setnames(setDT(transpose(lst)), c("CODE", "VAL"))[]
```

where

```
lst <- list(c("PACKAGE"    ,"OptimizeR"              ),
            c("RCALL"      ,"optimizeR_jar"          ),
            c("var_PRODUCT", "PRODUCT_CODE"          ),
            c("var_JAR"    ,"SUGAR_JAR"              ),
            c("var_JAR"    ,"STRENGTH_JAR"           ),
            c("candidat"   ,"C18"                    ),
            c("benchmark"  ,"L23"                    ),
            c("var_TARGET" ,"PRODUCT_OVERALL_OPINION"))
```